# using custom material for an object

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recently migrated to ROS fuerte from electric. I have an object (floor) in ROS electric for which I used the material Gazebo/LightWood. Now that Gazebo/LightWood material is no longer supported in ROS fuerte, how do I use LightWood texture for my object. I do not want my object to look plain in one colour (brown or sienna). I tried the following code but I got errors.

```
<visual name='floor_3_geom_visual' cast_shadows='1' laser_retro='0.000000' transparency='0.000000'>
          <origin pose='0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000'/>
          <geometry>
            <box size='4.465000 4.000000 0.050000'/>
            
            <material> <texture filename="/home/angenuser/Desktop/hardwood_floor.jpg"/>
        </material>
            
          </geometry>
                 
        </visual>
```

And also, in general could someone give me the code snippet on how to add custom image to an object using a .jpg file. Eg situation: I have a tele-conferencing robot and I would like to put up a static jpg image on its screen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1706/using-custom-material-for-an-object/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/247/prasanna.kumar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/247/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-09**:
Found the answer for the first part from [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/242/how-to-modify-the-color-or-material-of-link-in/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

here is an example of how to use different textures:

```
            <material>
                <script>
                    <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
                    <name>Gazebo/Wood</name>
                </script>
            </material>
```

For adding an image on a model you can create a new material script, something similar to:

```
material pancake/2sides
{
  receive_shadows on
  
  technique
  {
    pass
    {
      ambient 1 1 1 1.000000
      diffuse 1 1 1 1.000000
      specular 0.03 0.03 0.03 1.000000 
      emissive 0.900000 0.900000 0.900000 1.000000

      texture_unit
      {
        texture pancake-sides.jpg
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where **texture pancake-sides.jpg** is the line where you add the image.

Or another possibility you could create a collada file, and export it with the texture. And then add it to the model as a mesh. [Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/beginner/mesh_import) is a tutorial of how to load a mesh file.

Cheers, Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-06-02**:
Why do you use Gazebo/Wood for pancake? that is confusing

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2015-06-03**:
Wood is an example of a material that is already present in Gazebo, the second one is a custom material (created for pancakes)

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-06-03**:
So in that case it would be Gazebo/pancake  or pancake/2side